# Is there a Grey value for Opacity maps?

Tags: transparency

White present and black is ignored.  If I want a translucent effect, making it gray does not help?  I'm fooled because there are little holes in my opacity map that gave me the illusion that gray is translucent.  It is not?  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Translucency and Transparency are not the same things.

[Transparency and translucency - Wikiwand](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Transparency_and_translucency)

In short, a transparent material lets light go through freely, while a translucent material lets only some light go through and changes it on the way.

Using a half-transparency shader in your material will only approximate the "some light go through" but not the absorption and scattering of light.

There are tricks to fake these effects to some degree, I.E. by modifying your diffuse color in that area, or adding some roughness.

But instead of faking translucency via transparency and other properties, you could simply use the translucent shader node.

Comment: You mean the subsurface of the Principled BSDF?

Comment: Wait, you gave me a practical answer but my question was more straight forward.

Do Gray values give you partial "see through"?  Or are opacity maps always black and white only?  Based on what you're telling it's "Yes but I shouldn't do it?"

Comment: "see through" is transparency. Grey values can give you partial transparency. Note that in Eevee render engine, some transparency blend modes in the material's setting don't support inbetween values (i think "hashed" is the one to use most of the time, but I can't check right now). And no, I didn't mean the subsurface of the Principled BSDF. There is a Translucent BSDF if you want translucency. But if you want only partial transparency, just use any value between 0 and 1 and make sure you set your material to support that if you are on Eevee.

Comment: If you have any further issue, please edit your original post and provide more details, like screenshots of your material, or even upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link in your post.

Comment: I think the OP is only using Translucency as a placeholder word for "not fully transparent". If that is the case, the the TLDR is that yes, black = transparent, white=opaque, shades of grey = partially transparent.

Comment: Hi Chris, Apologies, but yes that is what I meant.  in the screen shot I've attached in my post, that's a dark gray strip but it is by no means black.  However, it's completely transparent when I render in eve.  So this led me to believe only black and white values are accepted.

Comment: Yeah, if you're using EEVEE, set the Blend Mode to Alpha-Hashed, or Alpha-Blend. The third option, Alpha-Clip, will let you set a threshold (grey level) and it will cut anything below that.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherBennett for detailing the Eevee blend modes, I'm pretty sure the default is "Alpha Clip"? And I tend to set it to "Alpha Hashed" most of the time and then play with the render samples, because "Alpha Blend"  sometimes produces weird looking faces.